# Как переопределить стили, заданный в js

Tags: javascript, css, веб-программирование, frontend

Я задал такие стили через js и понимаю, что они имеют приоритет перед остальными стилями, заданными в css, но в media запросах мне нужно переопределять эти стили, но они не применяются, так как разный приоритет стилей, вопрос такой, как можно в media запросах сбросить стили из js и применить те, которые указаны в самом запросе

```
if (document.querySelector('.best-articles')) {
    v.style.setProperty("margin-left", "calc(750px - 240px - 56px + 300px + 3%)");
} else {
    v.style.setProperty("margin-left", "calc(750px - 240px - 56px)");
}
```

[image: каку]

Comment: Желательно добавить рабочий код html/css для наглядности

Comment: https://48ec-46-172-28-114.eu.ngrok.io вот сайт для наглядности

Comment: Не определяй стили через `style` определяй через `class`. Т.о. и с приоритетами будет все нормально.

Comment: Использовать `!important` в CSS, но крайне осторожно

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы, воспользовался обоими способами, оба оказались рабочими, но я думаю лучше всё таки придерживаться определения через class

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется проще сделать с добавлением класса

css:

```css
.best-articles{
    margin-left: calc(750px - 240px - 56px + 300px + 3%);
}
.best-articles.active{
    margin-left: calc(750px - 240px - 56px);
}
```

js:

```js
if (!document.querySelector('.best-articles')) {
    v.classList.add('active')
} else {
    v.classList.remove('active')
}
```